# How to change already exposed module constant in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a constant defined in my module and it is already exposed to all clients and many clients using this constant directly.

```
module MyModule
  module Contants
    FRUITS_MAP = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Apple'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Coconut'
      }
    ].freeze
  end
end
```

Now the problem is, I want to add one more hash to FRUITS_MAP based on a condition.

```
if Account.enabled_feature?('Mango')
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Mango'
      }
```

Note: I don't have access to all the clients and I don't want to enforce a change in all clients but I want to add one more element to  FRUITS_MAP conditionally.

For a client X with 'Mango' feature enabled, FRUITS_MAP should contain 3 elements, but for a client Y with 'Mango' feature disabled should have only 2 elements in FRUITS_MAP. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just return a new array by the concatenation of `MyModule::Contants::FRUITS_MAP` and the additional object you want in it if the condition is true:

```
p MyModule::Contants::FRUITS_MAP + [{ id: 5, name: 'Mango' }] if Account.enabled_feature?('Mango')
# [{:id=>1, :name=>"Apple"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"Coconut"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"Mango"}]
```

Comment: if one client already used the constant like MyModule::Contants::RESERVE_MAP.each { |x| .....} how this proposed change impacts the client?

Comment: With `MyModule::Contants::RESERVE_MAP.each { |x| .....}` I think nothing, since each won't mutate the constant, unless there's something that does it in the block. The thing is you shouldn't mutate the constant. Just use it to create a new object.